# How do you use procedural toon eyes with Lightning Boy Shader (LBS)?

Tags: shaders, procedural, shader-nodes

When I added the Lightning Boy Shader to my scene, it broke my procedural toon eyes, turning them red.  The answer below shows how I connected it to work.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wanting to use procedural toon eyes with the Lighting Boy Shader, it worked for me by removing the Principled BSDF shader, then plugging the stylized eye shader directly into an LBS color node (you might need to add the LBS global node - the main LBS node you connect everything to).  I didn't use any other LBS nodes.

[image: Toon Eye Shader with LBS nodes]